# How quickly dealocate map which contains dynamically allocated memory as a value?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, unordered-map, stdmap

Map consists of string as a key and objects of A as a value. Function clear() from std::map/std::unordered_map won`t call destructor. I have to take care of dealocating memory by my self when I want to clear the map. Is it only one way to dealocate memory using for loop?
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
class A
{
public:
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }
};
int main ()
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string, const A*> mymap = { {"house",new A()}, {"car", new A()}, {"grapefruit", new A()} };
  //mymap.clear();//won`t call destructor
  for(const auto &i : mymap)
      delete i.second;      //dealocate value
  mymap.clear();            //clear whole object from tha map
}
```

Is it possible to do this faster, e.g. without using for loop?

Comment: Why do you need to dynamically allocate the A objects?

Comment: class A is the primary class in hierarchy. I need a pointer to use polymorphism.

Comment: @user3455638 You could add that information to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep!  Use `unique_ptr` and automate this.

(Note how I have converted `const A*` to `std::unique_ptr<const A>`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

class A {
public:
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<const A>> mymap;
  mymap["house"] = std::make_unique<A>();
  mymap["car"] = std::make_unique<A>();
  mymap["grapefruit"] = std::make_unique<A>();

  mymap.clear(); // Will call destructor!
}
```

Comment: The problem is with the cacheline. unique_ptr-s are between each other in the memory in the map, but the memory on which pointers indicate not?

Comment: @user3455638 I don't follow the last part, could you clarify what you mean?  Also the `unique_ptr` solution will have almost no overhead compared to raw pointers in terms of cache locality.  They are **very thin** wrappers around raw pointers

Comment: You are right. unique_ptr is thin pointer not as shared_ptr. I was thinking if elements will be situated in the memory within each other in the map when I use unique_ptr. This is map, so not.

Answer (score 3):

Use a map of `std::unique_ptr`s and just `clear()` it. Or just hold `A` objects in the map rather than pointers.